# Is it possible to refresh one view inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a standard table view. Inside each cell `UITableViewCell` I have a label. At any given time I need to constantly updating one label for the whole tableView (imagine a clock ticking for example).

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I recognize which cell I need to update and assign weak property to the label inside such cell.

Then later, I call

> label.text = @"New value";

and expect for that particular cell to refresh that particular label. I checked the weak reference and it's valid and text is changing, however cell is not getting refreshed.

I don't want to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, I just need to refresh one subview inside cell view. Is it possible?

UPDATE:

Here is my code:

This is property definition inside view controller .m file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel* runningTimerLabel;
```

I assign this property inside `cellForIndex` call:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    MKSlidingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"container"];
    TimerCell *foregroundCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTimerCellId];
    UITableViewCell *backgroundCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"background"];

    BOOL runningCell = (indexPath.row == self.runningTimer);

    if (runningCell) {
        self.runningTimerLabel = foregroundCell.time;
    }

    cell.foregroundView = foregroundCell;
    cell.drawerView = backgroundCell;
    cell.drawerRevealAmount = 146;
    cell.forwardInvocationsToForegroundView = YES;
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell; 
}
```

Here is the method that updates the label:

```
- (void)refreshRunningTimerCell
{
     self.runningTimerLabel.text = @"New text";
}
```

This method is getting called from a background thread:

```
- (void)refreshRunningTimer
{
    while (1) {
        sleep(_sleepTime);

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(refreshRunningTimerCell)
                               withObject:nil waitUntilDone: YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: Updating the text in a label does not require any extra updates no matter what kind of view its in (the table view should not be affecting this). You do not need to refresh the tableview or any rows if you have an outside reference to the label. Something else is wrong with your code, perhaps you could post the relevant bits and we can take a look.

Comment: Updated question with code snippets

Comment: Why are you set on not using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` ?

Comment: Because cell can be slided to the side at any given moment. If I refresh whole cell its sliding reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why you trying to get an reference on UIlabel.

You have self.runningTimer so you have a index row in your tableView, so just get

TimerCell *cell by cellForItemAtIndexPath and just update this cell.

Comment: Hm... This actually worked. I have no idea why. Storing pointer to the Label worked fine for regular cells, but didn't work for cell that slides - as you can see I am using `MKSlidingTableViewCell` for that. It has an extra layer of container-subview above my cell with content. But getting the cell and navigating it hierarchy down to the label and updating it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that cells are reusing during slide, you cannot just take a reference on view from your cell in your controllerView. Even is weak reference. This is realy bad pracise what you have done for me. Always if you want to update cell, get whole cell not object inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell updateLabel:@"New string"];
```

Comment: I think this essentially what I have. At the end you get a reference to the UILabel, which I saved before as well.