# How to number the rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to number the rows in my app, just like in excel. I use a label for this in the cell. I have written some code which does this perfectly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.numberlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li.",(indexPath.row+1)];

    return cell;
}
```

However the problem is, that whenever I delete a row the numbering does not get refreshed. So I thought maybe I would iterate through every cell and set the number again, whenever the user deletes a row. Here is what I did:

```
NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells];

int n = 0;

for (TableViewCell *cell in cells)
{
     n++;
     cell.numberlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.",n];
}
```

This works great, but again I faced another problem: The tableview is reusing cells so I can not iterate through each and every one of them, only the ones that are actually on screen.

**So my question is:** How would I go about solving this issue of properly numbering each row in the TableView, even if the user starts deleting rows?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you show in your question/ Simply reload the visible cells after deleting or inserting a row (and only if the inserted or deleted row is not after the last visible row).

Comment: @rmaddy he does not understand that other cells will be re-configured in data source delegate as user scrolls the table. Otherwise seems like a sane approach to manually update visible cells only.

Comment: The problem is that only the visible cells will be renumbered. And, if I reload the whole tableview after deletion, the deletion animation will be cut off and also it's not very efficient.

Comment: my problem is same as like you got , and i got fixed it by seeing this , thanks  @BalázsVincze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do the following:

1. Use your first approach by setting the label text in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method
2. Delete your desired row
3. Now do not reload the whole tableview but use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for all visible cells. All offscreen cells will have the correct row number as soon as they become visible because it will be set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Default" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", indexPath.row +1];
    return cell;

}
- (NSArray *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

        self.numberOfRows--;

        NSMutableArray *visibleCellIndexPaths = [[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] mutableCopy];
        [visibleCellIndexPaths filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"row > %i",indexPath.row]];

        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleCellIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [tableView endUpdates];



    }];

    return @[deleteAction];

}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm, very smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

i think first method be great

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     cell.numberlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li.",(indexPath.row+1)];

     return cell;
}
```

if user delete row, you simply can catch this and reload data and table view redraw with normal values

Comment: Hello! Thanks, but I want to avoid having to reload the tableview because the row deletion animation will be cut off when reloading.

Comment: try to see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995916/is-it-possible-to-refresh-one-view-inside-uitableviewcell

Comment: Thanks! I checked, I think my problem is a little different though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload the table after the deletion,
then you can use the following approach:
You can iterate through the cells.
Iteration will start from the indexpath of the cell which recently got deleted to the number of rows.
And you can reduce their number by one during iteration.

Comment: Yes, but what if the user deleted the second row and there are 50 rows? The ones that are not on the screen won't be updated. Or can you show me some code for iterating through all of them?

Comment: The cells that are not visible will be updated anyway if the tableview will scroll an the cells become visible